# How to test SyntaxNet trained model (Spanish UD)?

Tags: nlp, tensorflow, syntaxnet, parsey-mcparseface

Training my own SyntaxNet model for Spanish-Ancora UD corpus following the instructions from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet) did not give me errors.

After all the steps the final files it creates were:

```
-category-map  
-char-map  
-checkpoint  
-context  
-graph  
-label-map  
-latest-model  
-latest-model.meta  
-lcword-map  
-model  
-model.meta  
-prefix-table  
-status  
-suffix-table  
-tag-map  
-tag-to-category  
-tagged-dev-corpus  
-tagged-training-corpus  
-tagged-tunning-corpus  
-word-map
```

The context.pbtxt file used for the training was the one from syntaxnet/models/parsey_universal.

Then when I try to test it calling `parser.sh` from syntaxnet/models/parsey_universal return a couple errors:

```
F syntaxnet/term_frequency_map.cc:63] Check failed: ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (tensorflow::Env::Default()->NewRandomAccessFile(filename, &file)) (OK vs. Not found: syntaxnet/models/parsey_universal/modeltest/char-ngram-map)
F syntaxnet/term_frequency_map.cc:63] Check failed: ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (tensorflow::Env::Default()->NewRandomAccessFile(filename, &file)) (OK vs. Not found: syntaxnet/models/parsey_universal/modeltest/morphology-map)
```

Then I downloaded the Spanish pretrained model from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/universal.md). And I checked the files. It seems like there are two missing files, the pretrained model has it by default but in the one I trained, these files were missing.

So my questions are how to get these files in the SyntaxNet training phase?
there are other ways to produce them?
should I test it in a different way?

Comment: I can't even download the spanish language, seems like I need an access key, how do you get it ?

Comment: @JoseF download the model following [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/universal.md) instructions, just change the <language> tag for the models name you want it.

Comment: When I go to http://download.tensorflow.org/models/parsey_universal/spanish.zip , I get this error: <Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error> . Do I need permission for this or register in somewhere ?

Comment: I use the same just changing the <spanish.zip> to <Spanish.zip> it show me the same message than you but automatically let me download.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is parse_universal doesn't have these files:
`/parsey_universal/modeltest/char-ngram-map`
`/parsey_universal/modeltest/morphology-map`